# Firebase deploy fails after adding second project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

After adding a second project to my code using the command `$ firebase use --add second-project`, I get the error

> There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.
>
> Error: HTTP Error: 404, Could not find Application "second-project".

when I run `$ firebase deploy`.

I have added separate targets and a web app through Firebase console for the second project.

What should I be checking to get rid of this error?

Comment: The error message says to contact support, so I suggest contacting Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: In some cases updating the Firebase CLI version helped. Would you try this? [Check here for instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#update-cli)

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this same exact issue as well. Leaving this here for anyone that runs into this issue in the future. What caused this error for me was a permissions error, when Firebase tried to access specific resources in Google Cloud such as Cloud Functions without the necessary IAM/service accounts in place.

This happens when you create a new Firebase project without setting the `Default GCP resource location` under `Settings > General` in the Firebase Console, which occurs when you create a new Firebase project without doing any additional setup. You can set this in the settings or this is also set when you follow the walk-through instructions for setting up services such as Firestore or Firebase Storage in the Firebase console.

Without this set, the `<YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` IAM/service account will not be created in Google Cloud (which is needed to create/access specific resources), therefore when you run `firebase deploy`, it will fail with the error you mentioned above.

You can also check why your `firebase deploy` is failing in the `firebase-debug.log` that is generated when running this command (that's how I found out the cause of this error). Though I think this file is deleted after the command finishes execution, so you'll have to pipe the output into a file or save it some other way.

TL;DR: Set `Default GCP resource location`, one way this can be done is in the Firebase Console under `Settings > General`.